# Setting range in Word with VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

How do I set a range in Word while opening that file with VBA in Excel?

```
Dim wordApp As Word.Application
Dim wordObject As Word.Document
Dim wordRange As Word.Range

Dim filePath As String
Dim fileName As String

filePath = "C:\Users\"
fileName = "somename.docx"

Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

With wordApp
    .Visible = True
    .Activate
    .WindowState = wdWindowStateNormal
End With

Set wordObject = wordApp.Documents.Open(filePath & fileName)

Set wordRange = Documents(fileName).Sections(1).Range

With wordRange
    'code
End With
```

The line causing trouble:

```
Set wordRange = Documents(fileName).Sections(1).Range
```

Regardless of the string I put in this returns

> 4160 runtime error "Bad File Name"

If I use `ActiveDocument` instead of `Documents()`, I get

> 4248 runtime error: "This command is not available because no document is open".

The error persists even after opening multiple unsaved and saved Word docs whilst running the code, only to have the same error message show up.

Answer (score 2):

`Set wordRange = Documents(fileName).Sections(1).Range` errors because Excel doesn't know what `Documents` is (or it resolves it to something other than `Word.Documents`)

To fix that, you'd use (just as you did in the previous line)

```
Set wordRange = wordApp.Documents(fileName).Sections(1).Range
```

**That said, you've already `Set` the `Document(filepath & filename)` to `wordObject`, so use it:**

`Set wordRange = wordObject.Sections(1).Range`

---

Also, Excel doesn't know `wdWindowStateNormal`, so a new `Variant` variable is created (unless you have `Option Explicit`, which you should, *always*) and assigned the default value `0`.  Which just happens to be the value of `Word.wdWindowStateNormal` so no harm done, but the code is misleading.

To fix, use

```
.WindowState = 0 'wdWindowStateNormal
```

---

I'm curious about the way you've created the object. Using early binding but instead of creating `New Word.Application` you use `CreateObject`

- Was this an intentional decision?
- What is the benefit?

Comment: @chrisneilsen I'd guess the OP uses `CreateObject` because so many code samples here and elsewhere use it instead of `New`. Almost every question I see that manipulates another application from within Excel (and Access) use `CreateObject`. True, most also use late-binding, but not all... The answer here might benefit from an explanation of what early- and late-binding are and how to use them correctly since the OP almost certainly doesn't understand the difference.

Comment: @cindy yep, I agree.  That comment was the last of a back and forth that lead to the current version of the answer (don't know if you saw those) that's now been cleaned up. 
 Doesn't make much sense to leave it on it's own, I'll delete it shortly.  I don't think adding a discussion of early and late binding to _this_ Q+A would make sense, but do you know a good canonical that could be referenced?

Comment: @chrisneilsen I don't have a link, right off-hand, although I'm sure there must be one on the site. And yes, such a link would probably be better than a full explanation. FWIW I flagged the rest of the comments for clean-up, which is what prompted my comment. I'd also remove those questions at the end of the answer as it appears the OP is not responding...